# Merging & Combining 2 apps. [Reactjs, React Router]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've 2 apps and I want to combine them, how can I do it?
So for example:
First App1.js has it's own `<Header/>` and `<Footer>`
As well as second App2.js has it's own `<Header/>` and `<Footer>`

So when I combine in one single App.js the first App1.js is imposition elements of App2.js

Comment: Well, you'll need to identify the dissimilarities and commonalities between the two layout components to create just one for each section.

Comment: Is it possible, to give an example?